# Why is 'web mvc install language' not available?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-roo

I tried to add german language support to my ROO project by using the roo shell command

> `web mvc install language --code de`

the the following messaged appeared.

> Command 'web mvc install language --code de' was found but is not currently available (type 'help' then ENTER to learn about this command)

I understand that there's nothing wrong with the command but that there's some unsatisfied dependency or something. Please help, I've been looking the web but didn't find a clear answer. What prerequisites have to be met to get this to work?

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some commands you need to run first, have you run this one:

```
web mvc setup
```

Comment: thats not it, I did that before but I retried `web mvc install language --code de` some time later in the day and it worked. I don't know why. I'll mark your answer as accepted even though it didn't help :)

Answer (score 1):

Its not an answer. Just a little suggestion.
Roo does that, sometimes it says that the command was found, but not currently available (I got that while executing jpa setup command). It doesn't give necessary explanation.

In these cases,

1. you should look at your current roo focus. Check that you are indeed at the right place to execute the command.
2. Try cleaning the project by executing "perform clean".
3. Check the log.roo, see any previous command has failed.
4. In extreme cases(when your head is about to blow like mine ;)) copy the correct portion of the log.roo, then delete the project entirely and then execute the correct portion of the log.roo.

Hope that helps.